# How to properly trim string

Tags: wpf, string, vb.net, trim

I am trying to separate an entered name into 2 strings.

Each name is entered in the convention of lastName, firstName
or Ex: Smith, John

I would like to separate the name into a lastName and firstName variable by trimming the string before and after the comma and space.

I have tried

```
Dim nameSeparator() As Char = {",", " "}
Dim lastName = txtEditName.Text.TrimEnd(nameSeparator)
Dim firstName = txtEditName.Text.TrimStart(nameSeparator)
```

But after running this, lastName and firstName both equal the full string from `txtEditName.Text`

Comment: You should use string.Split and then trim the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "split" a string in two substrings using a certain separator then you should use the proper method: [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)

Only after the splitting you can remove unneeded characters at begin or end of a string using the [string.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) method

```
Dim input() as String = txtEditName.Text.Split(",")
Dim lastName = input(0).Trim()
Dim firstName = input(1).Trim()
```

Of course this example assumes that you have exactly the input described in your question. If you want to use this approach in a real application then you should check if the result from the splitting produces exactly two substring before trying to access the substrings